# Eclipse Workbench UI layout keeps resetting.

Tags: eclipse

I've searched the site but can't find an answer.

My problem:
Every time I launch Eclipse (IBM IID 7.5.1.1) my work space UI is reset to the default settings and I get an error dialog box which says:

> Unable to read workbench state. Workbench UI layout will be reset.

I do not lose my imported projects, just the UI resets.
The workbench.xml file inside the org.eclipse.ui.workbench folder keeps getting erased when eclipse tries to load the work space.

Things I've tried:

- Run eclipse with -clean and/or -clearPersistedState command
- Deleted org.eclipse.ui.workbench folder in .plugins folder
- Made sure that XML files in the workbench folder are read/write access
- Deleted .plugins folder
- Deleted .metadata folder
- Created a new work space and did not import any projects.

None of the above worked.
Here is the .log file in .metadata: (not sure if i should just paste it here?

```
!SESSION 2014-11-26 08:51:29.503 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.4.0
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr10fp1-20120202_101568 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120202_101568
JIT  - r9_20111107_21307ifx1
GC   - 20120202_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -showlocation -product com.ibm.wbit.feature.ide -product com.ibm.wbit.feature.ide --clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -showlocation -product com.ibm.wbit.feature.ide -product com.ibm.wbit.feature.ide --clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-11-26 08:51:34.894
!MESSAGE Module cannot be null
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Module cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.removeServerListener(Server.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServersView2.dispose(ServersView2.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.doDisposePart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.doDisposePart(ViewReference.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.dispose(WorkbenchPartReference.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.disposePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.partRemoved(WorkbenchPage.java:1713)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewFactory.releaseView(ViewFactory.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.dispose(Perspective.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.dispose(WorkbenchPage.java:1792)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.closeAllPages(WorkbenchWindow.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.hardClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1702)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$0(WorkbenchWindow.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$5.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$65.runWithException(Workbench.java:3637)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-11-26 08:51:34.932
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.computeBundleGroupMap(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.createNewBundleGroupsMap(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.getNewlyAddedBundleGroups(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.getWelcomePerspectiveInfos(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowRestore(IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$8.runWithException(WorkbenchWindow.java:1315)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-11-26 08:51:35.440
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:584)
    at com.ibm.wbit.ui.internal.logicalview.WBILogicalView.layout(WBILogicalView.java:3303)
    at com.ibm.wbit.ui.internal.logicalview.WBILogicalView$7.run(WBILogicalView.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    ... 23 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run it in a "normal" JVM instead of IBM's J9? There could be an incompatibility.

Comment: What do you mean 'run' it? 
I am just starting the IDE, selecting work space, and I get this error. I also have IBM RAD and ADT for android, and they have no issues.